# Android - Position image inside EditText

Tags: android, image, textview

I have a multiline textbox (EditText) for the user to enter a text. I need to limit the height of the text. User can also change the text size. So I need to draw a line in the textbox so the user know how much he can write. The line should be an image and positioned relatively in the textbox.

I think I know I need to extend the EditText in some way but I don't have a clue how to do it or if it's the right way...

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom view components in android. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) is a doc for reference. Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705809/android-how-to-place-an-animated-image-inside-an-edittext-that-we-can-show-and) question.

Comment: I think I will try to make my custom view component. Never done this but I will give it a try...

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you can use the shape and draw lines inside the shape and also you can set the height and width of the shape.

[Notepad example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) of the API demos will help you in your case.

Comment: This is a solution, but I think I need to have an image including a line and a text "Stop writing here"