# Android: a "working" image in an edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to have an image inside an edittext, that will change it's drawable with an animation while the user types, as follows:

[image]

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705809/android-how-to-place-an-animated-image-inside-an-edittext-that-we-can-show-and

Answer (score 1):

Place `EditText` and `ImageView` in `RelativeLayout` and when you change text, change image

**EDIT:** added sample code

1) main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="New EditText"
            android:id="@+id/editText"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/first_image"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

2) MyActivity class

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;
    private ImageView image;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initializeFormViews();
        initializeFormEvents();
    }

    public void initializeFormViews(){
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void initializeFormEvents(){

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // changes image after editing text in EditText
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.second_image);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: another way to use drawableLeft image, and change that property on another image when you edit text

Comment: could you add an example?, this method sounds more "clean" to me

Comment: Thanks, but I used animationdrawable instead to make a frame by frame animation, and added the image to the side of the edit text instead inside it.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to set the **CompoundDrawables** {Right | Left | Top | Bottom} property in the xml

```
<EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchedTxt"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableLeftt="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"/>
```

Comment: Yes, that i figured by myself, But i want it to also change, when a user inputs text inside the edittext...

Answer (score 1):

please use the xml code snippet given below as a part of your main xml file(responsible for UI):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget665"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="1dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/searchImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="2dip"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </ImageView>
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:background="#f5f5dc"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
        </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

place this inner class inside your main activity

```
public class SearchTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence prefix, int start, int before, int count) {



                if(!prefix.equals("")){
                    changeImageToProcessing();
                }else{
                    changeImageToIdle();
                }




    }

}
```

extract searchBar (EditText) and iv (ImageView) from your contentView during onCreate(), something like

```
searchBar = (EditText)contentView.findViewById(R.id.customer_search_edit_text);
iv = (ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.searchImageView);
```

attach text changelistenber to the searchbar edittext

```
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(searchTextWatcher);
```

add couple of helper methods who will be responsible to change image accordingly

```
    public void changeImageToProcessing(){

        iv.setImageResource(resId);// resid is the id of the working image
    }

public void changeImageToIdle(){


    iv.setImageResource(resId);// resid is the id of the idle image
}
```

//these methods are called from onTextChange() inside SearchTextWatcher class